# Make fails to find include files but they're there

Tags: compiling, make, ffmpeg

I have configured ffmpeg for Android using the following configuration:

```
./configure --arch=arm --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-27/arch-arm --enable-gpl --cpu=cortex-a8
```

When I run `make`, it seems to fail in finding errno.h, so I get the following error:

```
CC  libavdevice/alldevices.o
In file included from ./libavutil/avutil.h:296:0,
                 from ./libavutil/log.h:25,
                 from libavdevice/avdevice.h:48,
                 from libavdevice/alldevices.c:23:
./libavutil/common.h:33:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <errno.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ffbuild/common.mak:60: libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

This happens despite the fact that errno.h is present on my system, both in `/usr/include` and `/usr/include/asm-generic`. I changed the include statement in `libavutil/common.h` to `#include "/usr/include/errno.h"` and it now fails to find another file `features.h`. Is there a way I can tell make how to find these include files?

**Update**:
Something that I forgot to include in the original question and might have been important is the warning that I received after running configure is:

```
WARNING: /Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
```

I do not see any file named arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config in the said directory. Should I create one?
I also added another configure option `sysinclude` as follows:

```
--sysinclude=/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
```

But, make still fails to find errno.h

Comment: Are there any header files that you know **are** being included from the `/usr/include` or `/usr/include/asm-generic` directories? That would inform whether it's something as simple as the search path for your C compiler. (Called "search path" in cpp docs, gcc docs just refer to it as "Directory Options")

Comment: @cunninghamp3 no I am not sure any file from those paths are included.

Comment: You are cross-compiling. You are not supposed to include files from `/usr/include`, which is intended for the host. Instead, you should include files from the cross compilation environment. There is something wrong with your setup. Do you have a complete cross compilation toolchain installed?

Comment: @JohanMyréen yes I have complete NDK installed in the directory I specified by sysroot if that's what you mean.

Comment: @JohanMyréen please see the updated question. I receive a warning after configuration.